# Dynamic conditional carousel item selection in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working with Vuejs and Nuxt and would like to display a video in a carousel component along side jpeg and png images . The carousel component:

```
    <template>
    <section>
    <v-card
        class="mx-auto"
        color="#26c6da"
        dark
        max-width="1200"
    >

    <v-carousel>
        <v-carousel-item v-for="(item,i) in items" :key="i" :src="item.src"></v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>

    </v-card>

    </section>

    <script>

    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          items: [  {
    id: '1',
    content: '<iframe width="560" height="315" ' +
      'src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zjcVPZCG4sM" ' +
      'frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" ' +
      'allowfullscreen></iframe>'
     },
            {
              src: "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/sky.jpg"
            },
            {
              src: "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/bird.jpg"
            },
            {
              src: "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/planet.jpg"
            }
          ]
        };
      }
};

    </script>

    </template>
```

Based on The answer [Displaying video in Nuxt carousel component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55911243/displaying-video-in-nuxt-carousel-component) and https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MqBEqb

I need:

```
<v-carousel-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" v-html="item.content">
```

for a video and

```
 <v-carousel-item v-for="(item,i) in items" :key="i" :src="item.src"></v-carousel-item>
```

for a jpg. How do I dynamically add 1 or the other based on the object in the exported data array?

Comment: i dont think this is correct way to do that, it seems like this is vuetify, if it is you could use slot to pass video to carousel and you will probably nees some condtion based on type of data (image or video).

Comment: also your data.content is invalid string you should probably use backticks there instead of single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a trick by which you can implement your use-case. You can use the combination of both `v-if` and `v-for`. I did put condition based on either it is `content` or `src`. Additionally, I have added `id` attribute for all the data items. Here is the working link for the codepen https://codepen.io/arunredhu/pen/MdebLV

```
<v-carousel>
    <template v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        <v-carousel-item >
            <img v-if="item.src" :src="item.src"/>
            <div class="video-elem" v-if="item.content" v-html="item.content"></div>
        </v-carousel-item>
     </template>
</v-carousel>
```

Comment: The below mentioned answer is exactly the same thing, why write twice , I am kinda confused her e, isn't this part of code of conduct or something

Answer (score 2):

You can use v-for on the template and later use v-if to do the check and insert one or the other as demonstrated here.

`https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt`

`https://codepen.io/autumnwoodberry/pen/qXGjXY?editors=1010`

Answer (score 1):

You can use template and *v-if='item.src'*

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-carousel>
          <template v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
            <v-carousel-item v-if="item.src" :src="item.src"></v-carousel-item>
            <v-carousel-item v-else v-html="item.content"></v-carousel-item>
          </template>
        </v-carousel>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```